# Partial derivatives of an interesting function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Calculate the partial derivatives of the function
$ \displaystyle F(x,y)=\int_{x}^{ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{y} g(s) ds} f(t)dt $ where $f,g$ are continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Try the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Both you and the site would benefit if you would consider [registering your account.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) Also, if you find answers helpful, up vote them. If you find a "best answer", accept it by clicking on the check mark under the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define

$$ \displaystyle H(x,y)=\int_{x}^{ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{y}  ds \: g(s)} f(t)dt$$

$$ \displaystyle H(x,y) = F \left [ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{y} ds \: g(s) \right ] - F(x) $$

where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.  Then

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -F'(x) = -f(x) $$

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = f \left [ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{y} ds \: g(s) \right ] g(y) $$